# Cannot convert from Discord.ActivityType to Discord.IActivity C# Discord.Net

Tags: c#, .net, discord, discord.net

This is the command that i will use when setting the activity but im not quite sure how to set it.

```
   [Command("watch")]
   [RequireOwner]
   public async Task SetBotWatching([Remainder] string video)
    {

        await XyntaxBot.Client.SetActivityAsync(ActivityType.Watching);
        await ReplyAsync("Set Activity");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An `ActivityType` has nothing to do with an `IActivity`; as the name implies, `ActivityType` defines the type of activity. What you should do is pass in an instance of `Game` with the specified activity type.

For example, you may want to do `Context.Client.SetActivityAsync(new Game("a video", ActivityType.Watching));`.

Additionally, avoid setting your client as a `public static`. The client object is already available to you with `Context.Client` under a command context.